# Change Bottom Left Vertical Radius React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to make a background using two View to look , but I am falling to set the "start" of the radius on the left size.

The result I get using :

```
  borderBottomLeftRadius: '20%',

  borderBottomRightRadius: '40%',
```

Is this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

I want the "radius" start more vertically

Any tips how I get this effect?

Thank you

Comment: It is for react native aplication

Comment: https://codepen.io/rod911/pen/PoboEeg anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact shaping like this through radius is probably not possible, I achieved this by use of `transform: [{ scale }]`

Here is the code

```
const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
<View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#00ffff',
        borderBottomLeftRadius: width / 3,
        borderBottomRightRadius: width / 2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'black',
        height: width / 2,
        width: width,
        transform: [{ scale: 1.4 }],
      }}
    />
```

Here what it looks like, is this workable for you?
you can tweak the values a little bit to meet your requirement.
[image]